# ESlint IDE not formatting in Sibling Directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I feel like I must be missing something really simple here, but for all my searching and going over the docs, I just cannot find a solution to this problem.

I have an inherited file structure (which at the moment cannot change) that looks like this:

```
- Folder 1
  -Web Files Folder
- Folder 2 (root)
  - .eslintrc.js
```

Folder 1 and 2 are siblings of one another, my main set of js, jsx, ts and tsx are set up in the `Web Files Folder`, and my eslint and webpack configs, package.json and entry point files are all in `Folder 2`.

I cannot seem to get the IDE (in this case VS Code) to effectively lint the files within the `Web Files Folder`. I have tried a whole host of things, the latest of which was trying to use overrides in my `.eslintrc.js` file to point to the relevant directory:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es6: true,
        jest: true,
        jquery: true,
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'eslint-config-prettier',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
        'prettier',
        'prettier/@typescript-eslint'
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        jsx: true,
        ecmaVersion: 2020
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'prettier', 'jsx-a11y', 'jest'],
    root: true,
    rules: {
        'array-callback-return': 0,
        'consistent-return': 0,
        ...
    },
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            node: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
            }
        },
        react: {
            version: 'detect'
        }
    }
    overrides: [
      {
        files: ['../Folder 1/Web Files Folder/*.js', '../Folder 1/Web Files Folder/*.jsx', '../Folder 1/Web Files Folder/*.ts', '../Folder 1/Web Files Folder/*.tsx']
      },
  ]
};
```

This results in the error in the Eslint console: `Invalid override pattern (expected relative path not containing '..')`

However nothing I have tried works. I am not worried about the linting in the build, only getting the errors to appear in the IDE and resolve on save (which works perfectly if I place the files within `Folder 2`)

I am looking for a solution which I can use in my `eslintrc.js` file rather than any changes to settings in the IDE if possible. Something like

```
project: ['./**/*', '../Folder 1/Web Files Folder/**/*']
```